# Docker Registry - Do not allow pushing if the tag already exits (except for :latest tag)

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I have a scenario where we need our private Docker Registry (v2) to not accept pushes to a tag if it already exists.

For example I have

```
192.168.0.77:5000/my-project:1.0.0
```

and someone pushes an update on the endpoint above. It should stop the push.

Then when the user pushes with tag 1.0.1 or any other, it will push successfuly.

I know Docker allows pushing on the same tag, however I wish to have this kind of workflow so we don't override each other's image this way and also these will co-relate with a Jenkins build (for transaction purposes).

Deployment Instructions (in bash)

```
 docker login -u admin -p fakepassword 192.168.0.77:5000
 docker tag my-project 192.168.0.77:5000/my-project:1.0.0
 docker push 192.168.0.77:5000/my-project:1.0.0
```

Can someone please advice a way of achieving this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32113330/check-if-imagetag-combination-already-exists-on-docker-hub

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if image:tag combination already exists on docker hub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32113330/check-if-imagetag-combination-already-exists-on-docker-hub)

Comment: Why not to use Nexus? It allows re-pushing image:tag

Answer (score 2):

This is what I use in my CI pipeline.

Check the value of `$?`, which contains the result of the most recent command - in your case a command that checks if the tag already exists:

```
#!/bin/bash

docker manifest inspect $IMGNAME:$IMGTAG
RESULT=$?
if [ $RESULT == 0 ]; then
  echo success
else
  echo failed
fi
```

Save it as a file and call it `script.sh`

To run the script:`sh ./script.sh`

The script will return 'success' if the command is successful otherwise it will return 'failed'

Answer (score 1):

The term you're looking for is immutable tags or tag locking. This is a feature of registry servers. If you trust the tooling pushing to the registry, then you can check for an existing tag with various tools:

- `docker manifest inspect` (I'm not certain if this is always a remote pull, treat this as experimental)
- `docker buildx imagetools inspect` (this command is hidden, which may mean it will change in the future)
- crane (from Google's go-containerregistry)
- regctl image digest (from myself, the digest does a HEAD request which is faster and better for registries that rate limit requests)
- skopeo (from RedHat)

With each of these, you're looking for error conditions that trigger when the tag is missing and don't care about the output:

```bash
if regctl image digest ${some_image} >/dev/null 2>&1; then
  echo image exists, skip push
else
  echo image missing, push new tag
fi
```