# Azure docker registry - bash script to check if a docker tag already exists

Tags: bash, azure, docker, azure-container-registry

What I need is to build an image (as a CI product) and push it only if the tag version is not on our private azure hosted docker registry already.

Following this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32113330/check-if-imagetag-combination-already-exists-on-docker-hub) I tried to replicate the bash script there with the azure registery login server but it does not seem to support the exact same api (getting a 404). How can I achieve this "check if version/tag exists in registry" via the http/REST api with azure container registry? (Without using the built in az tool)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I achieve this "check if version/tag exists in registry" via
>   the http/REST api with azure container registry?

In Azure container registry, we should use `Authorization: Basic` to authenticate it.

You can use ACR username and password to get the credentials, then use this script to list all tags:

```
export registry="jasonacrr.azurecr.io"
export user="jasonacrr"
export password="t4AH+K86xxxxxxx2SMxxxxxzjNAMVOFb3c" 
export operation="/v2/aci-helloworld/tags/list" 
export credentials=$(echo -n "$user:$password" | base64 -w 0) 
export catalog=$(curl -s -H "Authorization: Basic $credentials" https://$registry$operation)
echo "Catalog"
echo $catalog
```

Output like this:

```
[root@jasoncli jason]# echo $catalog
{"name":"aci-helloworld","tags":["v1","v2"]}
```

Then you can use shell to check the tag existing or not.

Hope this helps.

---

**Update:**

More information about Azure container registry integration with Azure AD, please refer to this [article](https://github.com/Azure/acr/blob/master/docs/AAD-OAuth.md).

Comment: Thanks, can you please point to the docs showing this? I was searching for this for quite a while

Comment: Strange I get an authorization error: ```{"errors":[{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED","message":"authentication required","detail":[{"Type":"repository","Name":"myrepo","Action":"pull"}]}]}```

Comment: @alonisser  have you enable ACR user login?

Comment: You mean admin user flag?
 I can do docker login https://$registry -u $user -p $password with the credentials supplied

Comment: @alonisser  Sorry, I am out of office now, I will check it tomorrow:)

Comment: @alonisser Could you please check your script and user name and password, When I use wrong password, I get the same error message as you.

Comment: @alonisser I have update my answer with ACR docs, please check it. that script works fine, please try it:)

Comment: Works! thanks. the problem was jq (I was using to extract the username in the script from acr response) was adding extra " around the string, using ```jq -r``` solved it, so the hash was now correct