# Check if Docker image exists in cloud repo

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-build

Say I have this image tag "node:9.2" as in `FROM node:9.2`...

is there an API I can hit to see if image with tag "node:9.2" exists and can be retrieved, before I actually try `docker build ...`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if image:tag combination already exists on docker hub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32113330/check-if-imagetag-combination-already-exists-on-docker-hub)

Answer (score -10, accepted):

Yes.

```
docker image pull node:9.2
```

Comment: hmmm, I don't want to actual download the image, just check if it exists, does this do that?

Comment: @AlexanderMills if the image is available it will download the image

Comment: yeah in this case I am just looking to ping the Docker hub server/registry to see if the image exists - this is so I can give the user a good warning if the image doesn't exist, in advance instead of making them wait too long

Comment: What if the image exists, but it is private and the user does not have access?  I suspect from an API pov it is the same as if the image did not exist.

Comment: Is there a command like this that doesn't require auth? In order to get this to work, I first had to run `docker login -u <username> -p <password>` ...

Comment: @AlexanderMills I seriously doubt it.

Comment: hmmm yeah, contrary evidence would be that I can install Docker images without authenticating. E.g., I can do `docker build` with an image that I don't have on my local machine yet, and still I don't have to auth. So there must be some pull command that doesn't require auth?

Comment: If private/img is an image you dont have locally and `docker image pull priv/img` fails bc lack of authentication but you can build a Dockerfile like `FROM priv/img ...` then i am not sure what is the point pf authentication.

Comment: I also use this way because curl responds with 404. Image with tag is definitely exists.

Answer (score 8):

This script will build only if image not exist.

**update for V2**

```
function docker_tag_exists() {
    curl --silent -f -lSL https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/$1/tags/$2 > /dev/null 
}
```

Use above function for v2

```
#!/bin/bash
function docker_tag_exists() {
    curl --silent -f -lSL https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/$1/tags/$2 > /dev/null 

}

if docker_tag_exists library/node 9.11.2-jessie; then
    echo "Docker image exist,...."
    echo "pulling existing docker..."
    #so docker image exist pull the docker image
    docker pull node:9.11.2-jessie
else 
    echo "Docker image not exist remotly...."
    echo "Building docker image..."
    #build docker image here with absoult or retlative path
    docker build -t nodejs .

fi
```

With little modification from the link below.
If the registry is private u check this link [With username and password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32113330/check-if-imagetag-combination-already-exists-on-docker-hub)

Comment: thanks! do you an example using v2 of the Docker registry?

Comment: cool thanks, this worked: `curl --silent -f -lSL https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/library/node/tags`

Comment: So I guess `https://hub.docker.com/v2` does not required auth, but `https://registry-1.docker.com/v2` does require auth?

Comment: auth only required if you are pulling from private repo not in this case

Comment: Will this give a false negative if there's a network hiccup during the check?

Answer (score 3):

If you have `"experimental": enabled` set for the Docker daemon then you can use this command:

> docker manifest inspect node:9.2