# Can I query an OpenShift Docker repository whether a given image _exists_ without pulling it?

Tags: docker, openshift

I have a situation where I need to wait for an image to show up on a given docker registry (this is an OpenShift external registry) before continuing my script with additional oc-commands.

Before that happens, the external docker registry has no knowledge what so ever of this image.  Afterwards it is available as :latest.

Can this be done programatically?  (Preferably without trying to download the image)

My order of preference:

1. `oc` command
2. `docker` command
3. A REST api (using oc or docker credentials)

Comment: `docker search <container>` responds with all matches.

Comment: @Marcel Is this for dockerhub only or can it be used with a given registry too?

Comment: I think it should work with any registry.

Answer (score 0):

assuming the repository from openshift works similarly to dockerhub, you can do this:

```
curl --silent -f -lSL https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/$1/tags/$2 > /dev/null
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32113330/check-if-imagetag-combination-already-exists-on-docker-hub/37799618)