# What is the right way to free up kubernetes resources for a kubernetes job that fails pulling the image?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-jobs

**Context**

We have long running kubernetes jobs based on docker containers.
The containers needs resources (eg 15gb memory, 2 cpu) and we use autoscaler to scale up new worker nodes at request.

**Scenario**

Users can select the version of the docker image to be used for a job, eg 1.0.0, 1.1.0, or even a commit hash of the code the image was build from in test environment.

As we leave the docker tag to be freetext, the user can type a non-existing docker tag. Because of this the job pod comes in ImagePullBackOff state. The pod stays in this state and keeps the resources locked so that they cannot be reused by any other job.

**Question**

What is the right solution, that can be applied in kubernetes itself, for failing the pod immediately or at least quickly if a pull fails due to a non existing docker image:tag?

**Possibilities**

I looked into backofflimit. I have set it to 0, but this doesn't fail or remove the job. The resources are of course kept as well.

Maybe they can be killed by a cron job. Not sure how to do so.

Ideally, resources should not even be allocated for a job with an unexisting docker image. But I'm not sure if there is a possibility to easily achieve this.

Any other?

Comment: You can use activeDeadlineSeconds when your job goes ImagePullBackOff state

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After Looking at your design, I would recommend to add [InitContainer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) to Job specification to [check existence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32113330/check-if-imagetag-combination-already-exists-on-docker-hub) of docker images with the given tag.

If the image with the tag doesn't exist in the registry, InitContainer can report an error and fail the Job's Pod by exiting with non-zero exit code.

After that Job's Pod will be [restarted](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/#pod-backoff-failure-policy). After certain amount of attempts Job will get `Failed` state. By configuring [.spec.ttlSecondsAfterFinished](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/#ttl-mechanism-for-finished-jobs) option, failed jobs can be wiped out.

> If a Pod’s init container fails, Kubernetes repeatedly restarts the Pod until the init container succeeds. However, if the Pod has a restartPolicy of Never, Kubernetes does not restart the Pod.

If the image exists, InitContainer script exits with zero exit code and the main Job container image is going to be pulled and container starts.

Comment: This seems like a good solution. I will give it a try and give feedback

Answer (score 1):

When a Job completes, no more Pods are created, but the Pods are not deleted either.

By default, a Job will run uninterrupted unless a Pod fails (restartPolicy=Never) or a Container exits in error (restartPolicy=OnFailure), at which point the Job defers to the **.spec.backoffLimit** described above. Once .spec.backoffLimit has been reached the Job will be marked as failed and any running Pods will be terminated.

Another way to terminate a Job is by setting an active deadline. Do this by setting the **.spec.activeDeadlineSeconds** field of the Job to a number of seconds. The **activeDeadlineSeconds** applies to the duration of the job, no matter how many Pods are created. Once a Job reaches activeDeadlineSeconds, all of its running Pods are terminated and the Job status will become type: Failed with reason: DeadlineExceeded.

Note that a Job’s **.spec.activeDeadlineSeconds** takes precedence over its **.spec.backoffLimit**. Therefore, a Job that is retrying one or more failed Pods will not deploy additional Pods once it reaches the time limit specified by **activeDeadlineSeconds**, even if the backoffLimit is not yet reached.

Here is more information: [jobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/#handling-pod-and-container-failures).

You can also set-up [concurrencyPolicy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/#concurrency-policy) of [cronjob](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/) to **Replace** and replace the currently running job with a new job.

Here is an example:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: hello
spec:
  schedule: "*/2 * * * *"
  concurrencyPolicy: Replace
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: hello
            image: busybox
            args:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - date; echo Hello from the Kubernetes cluster && sleep 420
          restartPolicy: Never
```

Setting **Replace** value for **concurrencyPolicy** flag means if it is time for a new job run and the previous job run hasn’t finished yet, the cron job replaces the currently running job run with a new job run.

Regardless of this solutions your problem lies in wrong images so automated deleting pods or jobs doesn't solve problem. Because if you don't change anything in definition of jobs and images your pods will still fail after creating job again.

Here is example of troubleshooting for Error: ImagePullBackOff Normal BackOff: [ImagePullBackOff](https://managedkube.com/kubernetes/k8sbot/troubleshooting/imagepullbackoff/2019/02/23/imagepullbackoff.html) .

Comment: Sorry, I think this answer misses the Context, Scenario and Question above. 
There is a just a job for which the pod is in status Waiting, because the image cannot be pulled (eg it does not exist). The question there is, is there a solution in kubernetes itself, so that it will release its node resources. (without needing an external process that uses a kube api to eg abort or remove the job)

Comment: Does the problem still exist ?

Comment: The accepted answer is not perfect. There are many reasons for a pod to start, like volume mount failed, not just ImagePullbackOff.

Set job's `activeDeadlineSeconds` is nice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `failedJobsHistoryLimit` for failed jobs and `successfulJobsHistoryLimit` for success jobs

With these two parameters, you can keep your job history clean

`.spec.backoffLimit` to specify the number of retries before considering a Job as failed.

Comment: Thx, but I think the failedJobsHistoryLimit only applies to jobs with state failed. In this case the job is in state waiting with reason ImagePullBackOff.

Comment: @timv do you mean the job starts and doesn't found the image and the state is not failed? did you already tried?

Comment: "I think the failedJobsHistoryLimit only applies to jobs with state failed. In this case the job is in state waiting with reason ImagePullBackOff." --> maybe add a liveness check?

Comment: @c4f4t0r Indeed it keeps retrying.

The pod status is Pending

The container status is Waiting, reason ImagePullBackOff

Pod events:

  Warning  Failed             23m (x3 over 23m)  kubelet Failed to pull image "XXX": manifest for XXX not found

  Warning  Failed             23m (x3 over 23m)  kubelet Error: ErrImagePull

  Normal   Pulling            22m (x4 over 23m)  kubelet pulling image "XXX"

  Warning  Failed             8m (x68 over 23m)  kubelet Error: ImagePullBackOff

  Normal   BackOff            3m (x90 over 23m)  kubelet Back-off pulling image "XXX"

Comment: @SylarBenes I believe that startup/liveness/readiness probes are for a pod that is already running. Probes are not yet activated for pods that are not yet running.